# How to get the details of the subtracted results in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm trying to get the details/case number of the results from the multiple columns I have subtracted.

For example: CountColumn_1 - Column_2 - Column3 = 40.
I created a calculated field and simply did COUNTD([column1])-COUNT([column2])-COUNT([datasource2].[column3])

Column3 comes from my 2nd data source. I am using 2 in total.

Now my problem is finding the details of the 40. What I did to get the results is:

Created 2 sheets, 1st sheet has the calculation  and 2nd sheet has all the case number. Created a dashboard and linked the 2 sheets, however when I  click on the subtracted results what it shows are all the case number from Column_1, Column_2 and Column3 that was used for the subtraction instead of the case numbers of the actual subtracted results.

Sample data screenshot:
[image]

If I click of the bar with the red arrow (which is the difference of the subtraction i performed), I am expecting to get the ticket numbers of the subtracted results, however what I am getting is the tickets that was used on the subtraction not the tickets from the actual subtracted results.

Comment: can you post sample data?

Comment: @Siva i have added the screenshot of the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

When you enable the "Use as Filter" button, Tableau will use ALL fields in the dashboard action.  What is happening is that it is sending the most restrictive set of fields to the list.

To set this up properly, go to the Dashboard Menu --> Actions.  You will see something like "Filter 1 (generated)".  Click on Edit.

[image: Dashboard action]

You can adjust the source/target sheets up top but what you need to concern yourself with is the green highlighted box.  Choose "Selected Fields" and select the field that corresponds to the "ticket numbers of the subtracted results" as you say.  If you see the "Missing fields on ..." (like I highlighted in yellow) then it means you need to add this field onto your source (bar graph) sheet (easiest place is on the Details shelf in the Marks Card).

Read more about [Dashboard actions](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions_dashboards.htm).

Comment: please kindly see my reply above with screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

@tagyoureit

I did that  Dashboard Menu --> Actions and on the Choose "Selected Fields" I selected the field that corresponds to the "ticket numbers of the subtracted results" which I believe is column that has all the ticket numbers right?. added the column that has all the ticket numbers as well on the Details shelf in the Marks Card as it's giving me the Missing fields on ..." (like you highlighted in yellow above)

, then from [image]

It became:
[image]

Comment: It might help to post the workbook/data to the [Tableau Community Forums](https://community.tableau.com/community/forums).  There could be other solutions here (including [Set Actions](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/actions_sets.htm) available in 2019.1) but would need to see the data to really dig into this one.